# Memory mapping and P/Invoke performance in C++/C# interop

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, memory-mapping

I have developed a few dlls a while back in order to P/Invoke some stuff from a C++ dll to C#. However, I work in a hard-real time environment and P/Invoke proved much too slow to perform certain operations.

So I came across Memory Mapping as a (supposedly) faster alternative to P/Invoke and during my tests, the C++ side of things didn't look too shabby:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("MyFileMappingObject");
char* pcTest = "Message from C++";

int _tmain()
{
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    LPCTSTR pBuf;

    hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
                INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
                NULL,
                PAGE_READWRITE,
                0,
                BUF_SIZE,
                szName);

    if (hMapFile == NULL) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"), GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    pBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(
                hMapFile,
                FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
                0,
                0,
                BUF_SIZE);

    if (pBuf == NULL) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"), GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
        return 1;
    }

    CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, pcTest, (strlen(pcTest) * sizeof(char*)));

    std::cin.get(); 

    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    return 0;
}
```

I adapted the code from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx

And here is the C# side:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MemoryMappedFile pagedMemoryMap = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("MyFileMappingObject", MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl);

        using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor fileMap = pagedMemoryMap.CreateViewAccessor())
        {
            var array = new byte[256];
            fileMap.ReadArray(0, array, 0, 16); //Take notice on this line
            var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(array);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

It works as intended, but there's an issue here: That fixed size for the byte array length in the ReadArray method. I suppose I'd have to write the length of the actual strings in my real application to a different share, then use it to read the string value, but that seems way too cumbersome. Considering that what I actually read from C++ in the real application are arrays of structs (which contain only strings, mostly), would I have any gain from memory mapping, performance-wise? I don't have any intentions of bloating stable code (albeit slow) with an alternative that might not have the intended results, so are there any real benefits to this approach? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: C# is not appropriate for a hard real-time environment.  The garbage collector will miss your timings.  In fact, Windows is not suitable for a hard real-time environment, since paging and interrupt-handling will miss your timings.  Soft real-time / near real-time is a different story.

Comment: Sure, we don't intend to have an 1:1 ratio. The C# portion is for visualization only and the values are updated constantly and quickly in a manner that it doesn't matter if we miss a few updates in the higher level. However, running everything using a soft real-time emulator works just fine, but once we connect to the real hardware, things get really botched

Answer (score 3):

Memory-mapped files are good for sharing data across processes.  They're pointless for sharing between modules in the same memory space.

Just define your data structure as a reference class type in the ordinary way, then pin it.  Now C++ can access the data structure directly using normal pointer access.

Counted strings will work just as well in pinned arrays as in memory-mapped files, except you won't need any kernel calls to set them up.

Comment: I liked your suggestion about pinning the objects. I'll try it out on Monday and report the results

Comment: is it monday yet?

Comment: @GregM it's several dislikes away from monday :)